# Ввод с клавиатуры  Perl

Tags: perl

Как в переменную $x ввести значение с клавиатуры в PERL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $x = <STDIN>;
```

Comment: @dionys Зачем Вам лишние переводы строки?

      my $x = <STDIN>;
      chomp $x;

Answer (score 1):

**А так лучше:**
`chomp ($x = <STDIN>);`